# How to return an array of pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have just made this code to calculate variance and mean of an array of numbers, but I can't find a way to return an array of pointers.

This is my function:

```
float* statistics(int numbers[], int numbers_len, float * ptr_mean,
float * ptr_variance, float * ptr_stdev, int * ptr_median){

  float*mean; float*variance; float stat[4]; float*array_stat;
  int i=0;

  mean=calculate_mean(numbers, numbers_len);
  variance=calculate_variance(numbers, numbers_len, mean);
  stat[0]=*mean;
  free(mean);
  mean=NULL;

  stat[1]=*variance;
  free(variance);
  variance=NULL;

  for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    array_stat=(float*)calloc(2, sizeof(float));
    array_stat[i]=stat[i];
  }

  return array_stat;
}
```

I need **array_stat** to be an array of pointers.
In **int main()** I call the function ***statistics()** this way:

```
int main(){
  int array_numbers[MAX_ITEMS];
  int n_numbers, i=0;
  float *calculate_statistics;

  calculate_statistics = statistics(array_numbers, n_numbers, ptr_mean,  
  ptr_variance, ptr_stdev, ptr_median);
  for(i=0;i<2;i++){
     printf("\n[%d] ITEM > %0.2f\n", i+1, *calculate_statistics);
  }
  free(calculate_statistics);
  calculate_statistics=NULL;
}
```

Someone can help me please?

Comment: At the moment `array_stat` is a pointer to an array of floats. The array has 100 elements, but you seem to be using only 2 of those. Why? And what's wrong with it?

Comment: @SzG I edited my code. The array has 2 elements now (mean and variance). How can I return it from the function ***statistics()**?

Comment: looks OK except in `main`'s loop you want `calculate_statistics[i]` instead of `*calculate_statistics`

Comment: If `calculate_mean` and `calculate_variance` only return a single value they should return `float` (or `double`) and not an array

Comment: @MattMcNabb so the function *statistics() it's ok and I should just update the main? Should I write **float calculate_statistics[4]** instead of **float *calculate_statistics**?

Comment: @DanielaFavia no, that would declare an automatic array which is not returnable .

Comment: Your question is unclear: your code currently correctly returns a dynamic array of some floats. Why would you want to change this to an array of pointers, and where would those pointers point?

Comment: @MattMcNabb sorry it was my mistake, now I understand your explanation!

Comment: Daniela, you've been returning the array all the time. A float array id and a float pointer behave very similarly. Just store the returned pointer and index it as an array. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

In statistics()

```
array_stat=(float*)calloc(2, sizeof(float));
  for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    array_stat[i]=stat[i];
  }
```

In main()

```
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
     printf("\n[%d] ITEM > %0.2f\n", i+1, calculate_statistics[i]);
  }
```

Do you only ever want an array of two floats? You might be better off using a struct.

Answer (score 0):

In C and such languages, "arrays" (not spécifically arrays of pointers) are half-baked data types which prevents to return them easily as a single object as you would like.

You can't have them as results returned by a fonction

```
 int[4]  foo(..parameters...) // no
 {
      int tmp[4];
      ....
      return tmp;             // no
 }
```

A common way to do it it to make the fonction allocate some space, and return a pointer

```
int*    foo( ...parameters...) 
{
     int *tmp = malloc(4 *sizeof(int));
     ....
     return tmp;
}
```

an thus the caller will have to deal with a pointer. Looks mostly like an array (you can use the [] notation for indices), but beware of memory leaks: you'll have to manage the deallocation.

Another approach is to call the function with an extra parameter: the address where the function will put the result.

```
 void  foo(...parameters...,  int results[4])
 {
      // do some stuff
      // put the results in, hum, results
 }
```

Calling sequence:

```
 int results[4];
 ...
 foo(12, 345, 6789, results);
 // here we are
```

So you won't have to manage allocation/deallocation, because the array is an automatic variable (lives on the stack) and, moreover, you won't have to copy data from array to array.